# Как вставить в текст все элементы массива, если дальше этот текст необходимо передать в activityViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как вставить в текст все элементы массива, если дальше этот текст необходимо передать в activityViewController? При дальнейшем отображении при шаринге все элементы должны отображаться с новой строки. Пробывал через for, выдает ошибку. B моем примере при тестировании элементы отображаются в каком то закодированном непонятном мне формате

```
var apple = [one, two,three,four]
let appText = "I have different apple: \n\(self.apple)"
let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [appImage!, appText], applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Тфкой вариант тоже не работает

Comment: let appText = "I have different apple: \n\(apple.joinWithSeparator("\n"))"      
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [appImage!, appText], applicationActivities: nil)
presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что понял вопрос, но все таки. что то типа такого подойдет:

```
let apple: NSArray = ["one", "two"]
let text = String(format: "I have apples here \n%@", arguments: [apple.componentsJoinedByString("\n")])
print(text)
```

Comment: Cпасибо, оно самое